# Entries in the program at startup

Tags: java, constructor

This is how its looking now. Not the entire version but where my problem is.

I want there to be a couple of dogs IN the program at startup that are added to the register/arraylist.

```
boolean toEnd = false;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Dog> dogRegister = new ArrayList<Dog>();

while (toEnd == false){

    System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do? \n Press 1 to register
        a dog. \n Press 2 to get a look at the taillengths of the dogs. \n Press
        3 to delete a dog from the register.\n Press 4 to quit.");
        int command = keyboard.nextInt(); //alternatives stored in "command"

    switch (command){ //Execute chosen command in switch-statement

        case 1: //User registers a dog 

        Dog d1 = new Dog(); 

        Dog d2 = new Dog("Mira", "Miniature Schnauzer", 1, 8);
        Dog d3 = new Dog("Jack", "Jack Russell", 3, 6);   
        Dog d4 = new Dog("Charlie", "Pug", 5, 5);
        Dog d5 = new Dog("Max", "Dachshund", 9, 5);
        Dog d6 = new Dog("Bingo", "Golden Retriever", 5, 12);
    }
}
```

**Dog Class**

```
class Dog {
    private String name;
    private String race;
    private int fage;
    private double fweight;
    private double taillength;

    public Dog() { //Constructor
        this.name = name;
        this.race = race;
        this.fage = fage;
        this.fweight = fweight;
        this.taillength = taillength;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a default constructor Dog()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future, please try to cut down the code you post to a [mcve] which *only* demonstrates they problem you're facing. In this case you've posted nearly 150 lines of code, but you could have cut it down to about 20, I suspect. The act of doing this reduction is often enough to solve the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a **no-args** constructor yourself:

```
public Dog() {
    // Code
}
```

Since you defined an **overloaded** constructor, the compiler **will not create a default one** for you, hence you get the error.

You can either instantiate your `Dog`s using the overloaded constructor, or use the default one plus the setters:

```
Dog dog = new Dog(name, race, fage, fweight, taillength);
// or
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setName(name);
dog.setRace(race);
...
```

Comment: Dog Doggy = new Dog();  is my testprogram and           public Dog()  in my dogclass it now works

Answer (score 1):

just add,

```
   Dog(){
    }

into Dog class.
```

> Generally, compiler gives constructor but only in that case while you
>   don't define any one, here you have define one parametrized 
>   constructor, so compiler won't gives any default constructor, so
>   either  add Default constructor which i suggest at top, or Always made
>   new Object with proper Argument.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Dog` you are creating a constructor with fields, but you should create a constructor without fields like this:

```
  public Dog(){....}
```

Than you can use it in another class of test like this:

```
 Dog dog = new Dog();
```